# How to reference xml data C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml file...

```
<xmlheufthdc src="http://172.16.7.50:8990/xml/heuft/hdc" version="1.0" time="2016-11-23T09:23:43.172Z">
<device name="2NG012550">
<entry name="count_total" status="valid">80849</entry>
</device>
</xmlheufthdc>
```

I have used c# and been able to access the data under entry name and entry status but i how do i make reference to the number 80849. ie what would i call it rather than name or status.

The code is as follows

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
    }

    public string add1;
    public string read1;
    public string att11;
    public string att21;


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    public void configureToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      form2.Show();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text1 = "";
        string text2;
        add1 = form2.add;
        read1 = form2.read;
        att11 = form2.att1;
        att21 = form2.att2;


        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(add1);
        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == read1))
            {
                if (xmlReader.HasAttributes)
                    text1=(xmlReader.GetAttribute(att11) + ": " + xmlReader.GetAttribute(att21));
                textBox1.Text = text1;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The att items are entred in another form and this is where i would enter. 
read1 being "entry" and att1 being "name" and att21 being "status".

Sorry im new to this any information would be much appreciated.

Thanks Alistair

Comment: Share the code you're using to "access" the xml. Are you using XmlDocument? XDocument? XPath syntax?

Comment: Hey, The code is as follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number can be accessed by using the InnerText property of XmlNode class.

Comment: Hey, Can you expand a little on this please i have added my code above.

Comment: XmlNodeList CNodes = xn.SelectNodes("xmlheufthdc/device/entry");
        foreach (XmlNode node in CNodes)
        {
            string na = example["Name"].InnerText;

Comment: Try this
XmlNodeList CNodes = xn.SelectNodes("xmlheufthdc/device/entry"); foreach (XmlNode node in CNodes) { string number = node.InnerText};

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try :)

Comment: Do I replace the existing XMLReader I have?

Comment: Can you please try ReadInnerXml() of the XmlReader class inside the if loop like this xmlReader.ReadInnerXml()